How to remove specific author in biblatex
How do I remove all instances of a specific author from each bib entry? Looking through the biblatex documentation suggested using source maps, but the following attempt makes biber crash (with the debug message internal error: stop == start for substring 0 if debugging is turned on) so I'm hoping for a different way.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match={John Doe}, replace={}]
      \step[fieldsource=author, match={Doe, John}, replace={}]
    }
  }
}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{one,
    author  = "John Doe",
    title   = "A paper",
    year    = "1984",
    journal = "A Journal",
    volume  = "1",
    number  = "42",
}
@article{another,
    author    = "Doe, John and Coauthor, Jane",
    title     = "Another paper",
    year      = "2024",
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}

I would want the output to be as if the bib entries had their author fields equal to {} (or not set) and {Coauthor, Jane} respectively. Is this possible without actually changing the contents of the bib file?
Kind of the opposite of Make specific author bold using biblatex but for use in a similar context.

not sure about the crash, but it is bound to give problems if you remove an author from a list and end with a dangling and:  and Coauthor, Jane. Beside this while I don't know the use case, it looks wrong to remove the author without trace, why don't you replace that be some text like replace={author hidden}?

I guess this is somewhat of an XY problem, but I'm curious about the present question anyway. I'm trying to output "with " if there's at least another author and nothing if I'm the sole author. The dangling 'and' seems less of a problem, it shouldn't be hard to adjust the match regex appropriately (and probably have a separate case handling the only author case).

This sounds like something you would do for a CV. Have a look at biblatex-publist and its \plauthorname macro.
